# No output from split up source, but no warnings either, when omitting an included file

Tags: c, gcc, dependencies, warnings

I ran into an issue invoking gcc where if I omit a library `.c` file, I got no output from the binary (unexpected behavior change) but since this is a missing dependency, I kind of expected the compile to fail (or at least warn)...

Example for this issue is from Head First C page 185 (but is not errata, see my compile mis-step below):

`encrypt.h:`

```
void encrypt(char *message);
```

`encrypt.c:`

```
#include "encrypt.h"

void encrypt(char *message)
{
    // char c; errata
    while (*message) {
        *message = *message ^ 31;
        message++;
    }
}
```

`message_hider.c:`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "encrypt.h"

int main() {
    char msg[80];
    while (fgets(msg, 80, stdin)) {
        encrypt(msg);
        printf("%s", msg);
    }
}
```

NOW, everything works fine IF I faithfully compile as per exercise instruction:

```
gcc message_hider.c encrypt.c -o message_hider
```

... but bad fortune led me to compile only the main .c file, like so:

```
$ gcc message_hider.c -o message_hider
```

1. This surprisingly successfully builds, even if I added `-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -g`.
2. Also surprisingly, it silently fails, with no output from encrypt() function:

```
$ ./message_hider < ./encrypt.h 
$
```

my gcc is:

```
$ /usr/bin/gcc --version
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Mindful that even with a Makefile, I could "still" end up with a missing .c file due to a mistake in the recipe.

Q: Is it possible to force a hard error if I forget to tell `gcc` about a `.c` file?

Comment: There is probably a function `encvrypt()` in the system library.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good answer! I just renamed everything to "encryptx" (header filename, function and prototype) then compile only the main .c file, and now fails with `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: _encryptx"`. Excellent!   Feel free to change to an Answer.  Is there a way to force an error/warning if your function is the same name as something in the system library?

Comment: Strangely, I don't see any other `encrypt()` in stdio.h, or files that stdio.h includes

Comment: There isn't any easy way to get warnings about functions defined in system libraries that you inadvertently use.  It's bad enough with documented functions (such as `encrypt()`; it is even worse with undocumented ("meant to be internal") function name clashes.  One of the more insidious bugs I had to resolve (a couple of decades ago) involved an "internal to us" function called `_bind()` being used by an "internal to them" system library — and the two functions did quite different jobs. That took a lot of tracking down. We renamed our internal function, and I now avoid names starting with `_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in a (misspelled) comment:

> There is probably a function `encrypt()` in the system library.

On a Mac, `man -s 3 encrypt` shows:

> CRYPT(3)                 BSD Library Functions Manual                 CRYPT(3)
>
> NAME
> crypt, encrypt, setkey -- DES encryption
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
>
> char *
> crypt(const char *key, const char *salt);
>
> void
> encrypt(char *block, int edflag);
>
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
> void
> setkey(const char *key);
> ```
>
> …

The [`encrypt()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/encrypt.html) and [`setkey()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setkey.html) functions are part of POSIX, so they'll be available on most POSIX-like systems.  Curiously, as shown in the manual page extract, the functions are declared in separate headers — [`<unistd.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html) for `encrypt()` and
[`<stdlib.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdlib.h.html) for `setkey()`.  There's probably a good (enough) historical reason for the disconnect.

You should have received a compiler warning about the function being undeclared — if you didn't, you are presumably compiling using the C90 standard.  That is very old and should not still be being taught; you need to be learning C11 or C18 (almost the same).

Since C99, the C standard requires functions to be declared before use — you can define a `static` function without pre-declaring it, but all other functions (except `main()`) should be declared before they are used or defined.  You can use GCC [compiler warning options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.3.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) such as `-Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes` (along with `-Wold-style-declaration` and `-Wold-style-definition`) to trigger warnings.  Of these, `-Wold-style-declaration` is enabled by `-Wextra` (and none by `-Wall`).  Be aware: as noted in the comments, `clang` does not support `-Wold-style-declaration` though true GCC (not Apple's `clang` masquerading as `gcc`) does support it.

Comment: Wise advice, TY. I got `unknown warning option '-Wold-style-declaration'; did you mean '-Wout-of-line-declaration'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]` but in Google I see it's not a typo, it exists, just maybe not in Apple's gcc. Updated my VSCode tasks.json for the other warnings, and `-std=C18`. I'm fetching Homebrew gcc now, as I want to prove to myself if `-Wold-style-declaration` would have triggered a message.

Comment: To future readers, Homebrew's gcc-11 does provide `-Wold-style-declaration` (where Apple's gcc does not).

Comment: So brew gcc with all warnings, still does not raise a warn/error if I omit the .c file containing the book's version of `encrypt()` meaning presumably it's picking up the system function version. I had hoped to go back to the problem and trigger some kind of warning (but maybe the nature of secondary system imports via stdio.h, makes this an impossibility?).

Comment: What I ran was: `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.3.0_2/bin/gcc-11 -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -std=c18 -g /Users/sprive/Projects/head-first-c/message_hider.c -o /Users/sprive/Projects/head-first-c/message_hider` same result as before.

Comment: Be aware that on a Mac, `/usr/bin/gcc` is another name for Apple's version of `clang`: `/usr/bin/gcc --version` yields `Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1` — `Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)` — `Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0` — `Thread model: posix` — `InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`

Comment: I was using a genuine GCC (GCC 11.2.0, compiled by me), which does support the `-Wold-style-declaration` whereas Clang (disguised as GCC) does not — producing the slightly outré message mentioned in the first comment above.  Running `/opt/gcc/v11.2.0/bin/gcc --version` yields `gcc (GCC) 11.2.0` — `Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`